# How to split line read from text file

Tags: ruby, file, split

I'm trying to read in each line of a text file where each line is formatted like this:

```
Bob,Daniels,40,50,60,70,80
```

I want to split the contents of each line based on commas but for some reason it's not working when I do this:

```
f = File.open("textfile.txt", "r")
f.each_line do |line|
  line.split(",")
end
```

What am I doing wrong here or is there a better way I could be doing this?

Comment: Your program has no lines that output anything so I'm not sure what you would expect.  Please give a [mcve] and a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: You are reading a comma-separated-value (CSV) file. Use the existing [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. CSV files look simple but there are a number of special cases that a simple, naive, `split` won't handle.

Answer (score 2):

You should save result of splitting, as example save it to variable:

```
result = []
f = File.open("textfile.txt", "r")
f.each_line {|line| result << line.split(",") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a CSV ("comma-separated-value") file, so use the existing [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. CSV files have a lot of special-case situations that a naive `split` won't handle.

The documentation has a number of different examples for how to read or write from/to files or strings.

For example, from [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-A+Line+at+a+Time) for reading a line at a time from a file:

> ```
> CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
>   # use row here...
> end
> ```

In your code the problem is:

```
f.each_line do |line|
  line.split(",")
end
```

`each_line` iterates over the file being read using an `each` block.

```
line.split(",")
```

splits the value but doesn't do anything with it, so the result is thrown away. You could assign the result to a variable or iterate over the resulting array:

```
foo = line.split(",")
# do something with foo
```

or:

```
line.split(",").each do |i|
  # do something with i
end
```

But again, the CSV specification is not simple so think twice before relying on `split`. For example, the following line is valid CSV:

```
this,"is,some,CSV",data
```

and should be parsed as:

```
["this", "is,some,CSV", "data"]
```

but `split(",")` will wrongly generate:

```
["this", "\"is", "some", "CSV\"", "data"]
```

and, because it's wrong, there'll be a lot of extra cleanup needed.

`split` will seem safe on a simple set of comma-separated values, leading you to think it's safe for everything until you run into the above type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Outputs last name field from comma-delimited-file:

**Program**

```
f.each_line do |line|
  fields = line.split(",")
  puts fields[1]
end
```

**Input** (textfile.txt)

```
Bob,Daniels,40,50,60,70,80
John,Smith,40,50,60,70,80
```

**Output**

```
Daniels
Smith
```